# How do I implement double Pow(double base, double ex)

Tags: c#, algorithm

If exponent is int so I can run loop for "ex" times.

If base = 2, ex = 0.5 so:

```
2 ^ 0.5 = sqrt(2)
```

If base = 2, ex = 1.5 so:

```
2 ^ 1.5 = sqrt(2^3)
```

All I think is with some if in it (if ex int? if ex negative?)

Is there a good way to implement Pow?

Comment: Why not use the [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may fit better to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @L.B IEEE 754 math has little to do with real math...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski IEEE 754  has little to do with the question.

Comment: @L.B what I mean is that this calculation will basically [require a Taylor series](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/21381), and no one on Math.SE will tell you how to do that properly without loosing too much precision because of the binary representation of numbers. Granted, this is math, but you need to be extra careful when reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski a) OP doesn't know  `Math.Pow` b) He wants to reinvent the wheel. What do you think the question is about? (BTW: i am open for a better site)

Comment: @L.B I'm afraid I don't see your point... of course it's *a)*, but then redirecting the OP to Math.SE doesn't make sense to me. (EDIT: IMO this is a solved problem and doesn't need to be redirected)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski But I think it is b). OP wants to do it for educational purposes. (This is what i understand from question)

Comment: @L.B I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. (OP should clarify this)

Comment: @Dmitry: You right, I can use it, but I want to know how does .Net implement it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Case 1**:
`a^b` with natural b (ie. a `int`-type, and ^ means power not XOR):
As you said, it could be solved with a simple repeated multiplication. But consider more efficient approaches like square and multiply:
Think of `c * a^b` with a variable c being 1; and of course following is valid:
`a^0=1`, `a^1=a`, and `a^b` with `b>1` is `a * a^(b-1)`

If b is even, `a^b` is `(a^2)^(b/2)`, in code-style `(a*a)^(b>>1)`.  If you think of variables a and b, just make `a=a*a;` and `b=b>>1;` and you have halved your exponent with just one multiplication and shift. *Instead of (b/2) loop iterations.* Just repeat the whole thing until you have divided b often enough to get 1, then a would be your result.

If b occurs to be not even somewhere during the process:
Now c is important: Initially, it was 1, now multiply a to it. `c=c*a;`
If you recall `c * a^b`, you can decrease b by 1 now because of one a is in c.
Now proceed with the even b like above...
Everytime you have an uneven exponent, let c accumulate the factor to get an even b.
If b is finally 1, `c*a` is your final result (it´s `c*a` everytime: if there was no uneven b, c is still 1)

**Case 2**:
`a^b` with negative b (be it natural of not)
That´s an easy one: `a^(-b) = 1/(a^b)` is an basic math rule.
Ie. ignore that b is negative first, but take the inverse of the result.

**Case 3**:
Generic real numbers.
Well, in **theory**, `a^b = e^(b*ln(a))`, and
[image: Exp]
[image: Log]
There are only natural exponents in it, so...

Practically, it´s inefficient and has a huge problem: Computers have limited decimal precision, and during the calculation you need more precision than the actual result will have. If you want 20 exact decimal digits, you´ll need exact calculations with eg. 30 (or some other number >20). Other way round: If you calculate with everything your CPU is able to, the result will be not as accurate (some wrong digits at the end). If you´re writing some bignum lib, you can probably allocate a large data type fitting for the smaller expected result, but that wont work with built-in CPU types.

Real implementations of methods like `Math.pow` are highly specialized algorithms adapted for certain CPU types, so that the actual wrong-digit-error is kept as small as possible. Additionally, it should be fast too, which makes the whole thing even more complicated code-wise. To get an idea how it can look like:
http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-2026/Source/Intel/expf_logf_powf.c
To understand how it works will require quite a bit mathematical and technical knowledge.
If you have no really good reason, something else to spend time on is probably more fun :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what I wanted to know, case 3!